# Using overloaded << operator with pointer of class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm defining a LinkedList class, which makes use of a separately-defined Node class. Each Node has a pointer to the next node.

In the Node class, I have 
`friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Node<T>& m);`

In the LinkedList class, I have head, which is a pointer to the first Node.

How can I define a print function for LinkedList that will iteratively call the overloaded << operator for each node in the list? SO far I have

```
void LinkedList::print() {
  Node* search = head;
  while(search) {
    cout << //print stuff here
    search = search->getNext();
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: does `cout << *search;` work?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: What Wimmel said should work, so we need more about "didn't work".

Comment: Is your Node class templated or not? From your operator<< it looks like it is, but from your print function it does not. Could you please confirm that? Also, it would be helpful if you paste more pieces of your code here

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, it is templated, the code I gave was just a simplification of what I had. When I did cout << *search, I had an undefined symbols error.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrtly I would like to refer you to a developed question:

[Operator overloading on class templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014294/operator-overloading-on-class-templates)

Secondly, here some stuff I came up with:

By writing:

`friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const LinkedList<T>& m);`

in class declaration you informed the compiler that you are going to use overloading of operator << to do something with the class(print it). Now you have to define the function.

Please note that it is a global function, not a class method.

Also I "fixed" two bugs in your code. One in the function declaration, in which the `LinkedList` should be an argument. Intuitive => Because you want to print the list not the node.

Second was in first line in which you have to take the m's `head` member's adress. In your "C'ish" implementation it is necessary.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const LinkedList<T>& m) {
Node* search = &(m.head); // You have to take the adrress of the head
while(search) {
   ostr << //print stuff here
   search = search->getNext();
}
ostr << endl;
return ostr;
}
```

This might seem a quite odd to return the stream but it actually makes sense in statement like:

```
LinkedList<Banana> bananas;
LinkedList<Apple> apples;

cout << bananas << apples;
```

Because `bananas` takes `cout`, uses it and then `return`s it to be used by `apples`.

Hope I didn't obfuscated it too much or made any mistakes.

Comment: I appreciate the help. What I was trying to achieve was to overload the << operator in the Node class, and make use of that in the function to print the Linked List, so Node was meant to be the parameter. Your implementation seems like it would work, but my problem lies in being able to print the Node using something like `cout << node_ptr`

Comment: Oh, I were considering whether you might have meant that. In this case it gets more interesting.

Comment: that why i asked it haha