# << operator overloading as a friend

Tags: c++, overloading

new to operator overloading and I'm getting an unresolved exteneral error message when trying to operator overload with <<. Error LNK1120 and 2019. Anyone know why? Thank you!

```
template <class Type>
class ListType {
 public:
 .. 
 friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const ListType &);    
 };

 template <class Type>
 std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const ListType<Type>& list) {
  if (list.head) {
    NodeType<Type> *temp = list.head;
    out << list.head->item;
    temp = temp->next;
    while (temp != 0) {
        out << "," << temp->item;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
  }
return out;
}
```

Comment: GCC 6.3.0:

warning: friend declaration `'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const ListType<Type>&)'` declares a non-template function `[-Wnon-template-friend]`
(if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add `<>` after the function name here)

Comment: Posted example doesn't provoke the linker error itself. Is this code placed in a header or source file?

Comment: [second answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014294/operator-overloading-on-class-templates) should explain how to do it properly

Comment: Ah sorry, this code is in the header file.
When i go to main I have:

       #include<iostream>
       #include "NodeType.h"
      #include "ListType.h"
      #include "OListType.h"
     #include "UListType.h"

     using namespace std;

    int main()
{
 
 OListType<int> list1;
        cout << list1;

Comment: Just saw the link, looking now. Thank you

Comment: [My answer to  another question about overloading `operator+`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35854179/434551) might be helpful.

Comment: Should probably be `template <class T> friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const ListType<T> &);`, but post an MCVE, please.